# Est-ce que la phrase « j'ai trouvé que ça a été » est écrite correctement ?

Tags: pronoms, démonstratifs

Je souhaite dire :

> J'ai assisté à la conférence du 24 avril et j'ai trouvé que ça a été excellent.

Cette phrase est-elle correcte ? Est-ce poli et formel ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ta phrase est correcte, mais elle fait un peu lourde, en particulier le *ça a été* n'est pas très heureux.

Tu pourrais aussi utiliser:

> J'ai assisté à la conférence du 24 avril et j'ai trouvé que c'était excellent
>
> J'ai assisté à la conférence du 24 avril et j'ai trouvé cela/ça excellent
>
> J'ai assisté à la conférence du 24 avril et j'ai trouvé celle-ci excellente
>
> J'ai assisté à la conférence du 24 avril et je l'ai trouvée excellente
>
> J'ai assisté à la conférence du 24 avril que j'ai trouvée excellente

Answer (score 3):

Ta phrase est bonne en soi mais pour l'alléger tu peux concaténer les deux propositions en une : *J'ai assisté à **l'excellente** conférence du 24 avril*.

Answer (score 3):

« J'ai trouvé que ça allait » sonne mieux, sinon [François a raison](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/9432/79) !

Answer (score 1):

***"ça a été excellent"***
Cette expression est formulée en passé composé. Ce qui suppose que l'action "avoir été excellent" s'est terminé au moment du déroulement du verbe/action. C'est à dire, au moment ou tu y a assisté.

Sémantiquement, cette phrase est fausse. Tu commences par un verbe au passé simple, puis tu continues avec un deuxième au passé simple (mais qui se passe après le premier) et au moment de donner l'information relative à ta phrase (ton jugement par rapport à la conférence) tu utilises du passé composé. Ce qui veut dire que ton jugement par rapport à la conférence est bien antérieur à tes deux premiers verbes...

Je suis perdu aussi.

Avoir été = Verbe être. Donc, vaut mieux utiliser le même temps de conjugaison pour décrire un évènement qui vient entre après avoir assisté à la conférence et maintenant.

WAOW, la vie devrait être moins compliquée quand même.
A mon humble avis.